# NPN BJT common emitter amplifier input impedance

Tags: bjt, npn, input-impedance

I am trying to find the input impedance of this circuit.

In this circuit 10K resistor is load.

I looked at my book but could not find any circuit looking like this because none of them has C1 capacitor. The input impedance must be 27K and beta of the BJT is 300.

Can you help me?

[image: circuit]

Comment: What have you tried? We don't give homework solutions here. We expect you to make a significant effort to solve the problem yourself and then ask a specific question. You said you were trying to find the input impedance and then you told us it "must be" 27k...what is going on? Where is the "common source" amplifier you promised us?

Comment: The actual input impedance is less than 10 kohm - can you see why? You are using LTSpice so why not use it to determine the actual input impedance?

Comment: you mean I put some DC voltage to V1 and look at how much current is drawn and divide to find Rin?

Comment: @EEstudent you begin a comment to someone like this `@someone`. Luckily I came back to this question and saw your comment else it would have been lost because neither Elliot or I would have been notified.

Comment: @EEstudent No DC current can flow from V1 due to C2.